# ironpython: How to call a chm Helpfile on Windows with parameters

Tags: ironpython, chm, helpfile

I´m trying to call a chm file in my IronPython code that has a reference to a specific chapter.

Calling the chm file works fine
Example:

```
  import clr
  clr.AddReference("System")
  from System.Diagnostics import Process
  Process.Start('''C:\planta\client\Help\Planta.chm''')
```

Calling the chm file won´t work ... can anybody help me?!?

```
  Process.Start('''C:\planta\client\Help\Planta.chm::/D-KA-0044095.html''')
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to accomplish what you are trying.

Sticking with the direction you started off you can determine the URL of the chapter and just try to launch it using [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx). This might open the correct help topic using a browser or similar viewer.

```python
import clr
clr.AddReference("System")
from System.Diagnostics import Process
Process.Start(r"mk:@MSITStore:C:\planta\client\Help\Planta.chm::/D-KA-0044095.html")
```

If you want to use Microsoft's help viewer you can launch it in a similar way.

```python
import clr
clr.AddReference("System")
from System.Diagnostics import Process
Process.Start("hh.exe", r"mk:@MSITStore:C:\planta\client\Help\Planta.chm::/D-KA-0044095.html")
```

A less error-prone way would be using [Help.ShowHelp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7y1a1xy.aspx) which handles your exact use case. The only possible downsides would be having to load [WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd30h2yb.aspx) and the fact that the help viewer attaches to your application/UI. So if you would like to start the viewer, terminate the IronPython process and keep the help viewer running you would have to take a closer look.

```python
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Windows.Forms')
from System.Windows.Forms import Help, HelpNavigator

helpFile = r"C:\planta\client\Help\Planta.chm"
topic = r"/D-KA-0044095.html"

Help.ShowHelp(None, helpFile, HelpNavigator.Topic, topic)
```

Comment: thank you very much ... i decide for the less error-prone way ... perfect!